# Create IconButton with shape Decorate give invalid constant value flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm new in flutter and I'm looking `IconButton` with oval background.

Here is what I'm using.

```
 Ink(
    decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
    color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,,
    shape: CircleBorder(),
     ),
   child: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.add),
      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      onPressed: () {},
      ),
 ),
```

Can you please let me know how I can add my `Theme` color in this button because I have dark mode also which changed button colors and background etc when dark mode enable by user.

Answer (score 3):

As per official docs [Link Here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IconThemeData-class.html) :

You should be able to set **color** by using **IconThemeData**

> Defines the color, opacity, and size of icons.
>
> Used by **IconTheme** to control the color, opacity, and size of icons in a widget subtree.
>
> To obtain the current icon theme, use **IconTheme.of**.

Therefore, IconButton needs to be given the color property as this overrides the IconTheme size property. If you want your button to have color derived from IconTheme then you should make your custom IconButton which sets the color for you.

... in your case, I'd pass - *maybe even store it in a separate variable like **currentThemeColor*** - the current color theme and set it here:

```
...
IconThemeData(size: 48.0, color: currentThemeColor)
...
```

Also, you might need to create your custom IconButton:

```
class CustomIconButton extends StatelessWidget {
  CustomIconButton({Key key, this.onPressed, this.icon});

  final Function onPressed;
  final Icon icon;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    IconThemeData iconThemeData = IconTheme.of(context);
    return IconButton(
        onPressed: onPressed, color: iconThemeData.color, icon: icon);
  }
}
```

Comment: Problem is not in `IconButton` problem is in `ShapeDecoration`

Comment: So, is it solved? if not, let me know so I can try to help with further investigation

Comment: I create the similar button using `FlatButton`

Answer (score 2):

Using `FlatButton` you can achieve same result.

```
FlatButton(
  onPressed: () {
  },
  color: Theme.of(context).hintColor.withOpacity(0.5),
  shape: CircleBorder(),
  child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
)
```